# How to format chart in Roassal 3?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, roassal

I made a chart following the examples in the documentation. I find the title and x/y labels too close to the plot itself, and the tick labels too small. How do I format them?

```
x := -3.14 to: 3.14 count: 100.
y := x sin.

c := RSChart new.
p := RSLinePlot new x: x y: y.
c addPlot: p.

c title: 'Sine function'.
c xlabel: 'X axis'.
c ylabel: 'Y axis'.

c addDecoration: RSHorizontalTick new.
c addDecoration: RSVerticalTick new.
c open
```

[image: chart]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way the graph is constructed it uses the default offset of `5` for `X axis` and `-5` for `Y axis` in the `initialize` of `RSXLabelDecoration` or `RSYLabelDecoration` respectively.

To move the titles around you have to create them yourself instead of using `xlabel` or `ylabel`.

You whould have to replace these two lines of code:

```
c xlabel: 'X axis'.
c ylabel: 'Y axis'.
```

with:

```
xAxisDecoration := c addDecoration: (RSXLabelDecoration new title: 'X axis'; offset: 15).
yAxisDecoration := c addDecoration: (RSYLabelDecoration new title: 'Y axis'; offset: -15).
```

The result:

[image: XY axis movement]

**Edit - forgot about the tick labels**

To adjust the font size you need to add a message `fontSize` when creating a `RSHorizontal(Vertical)Tick`

The affected code would look like this:

```
c addDecoration: (RSHorizontalTick new fontSize: 10).
c addDecoration: (RSVerticalTick new fontSize: 10).
```

Producing this result:

[image]